# Determine all real numbers $a$ for which the limit $\lim\limits_{x\to ∞ }a^nA^n$ exists and is non zero.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, limits

> Let A be the $3×3$ matrix
>   $$
> A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1&0\\-1&2&-1\\0&-1&1\end{pmatrix}.
> $$
>
> Determine all real numbers $a$ for which the limit $$\lim_{n\to \infty}a^nA^n$$
>   exists and is non zero.

My answer.  I think $a=1$, as I was not able to think how to tackle this kind of problem. Please help me or give me some hints or a solution.

I would be very thankful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $A$ is diagonalizable and its eigenvalues are $0$, $1$, and $3$. Therefore, the answer is $a=\frac13$. In fact, since there is an invertible $3\times3$ matrix $P$ such that$$A=P\begin{pmatrix}3&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}P^{-1},$$then, for each $a\in\mathbb R$ and each $n\in\mathbb N$,$$a^nA^n=P\begin{pmatrix}(3a)^n&0&0\\0&a^n&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}P^{-1}$$and the sequence$$\begin{pmatrix}(3a)^n&0&0\\0&a^n&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}_{n\in\mathbb N}$$has a non-zero limit if and only if $a=\frac13$.

Comment: @ Jose carlos santos sir  im not getting  as how  do u get $a\in\left(-\frac13,\frac13\right)$ ?  can u elaborate it ?

Comment: @lomberlego My previous answer was wrong, but I have corrected it and added more details.

Comment: thanks a lots @jose Carlos santos sir

Comment: Hmm... doesn’t it converge for $a\in\left(-\frac13,\frac13\right]$?

Comment: @amd Read the problem again. The goal is to converge to a non-zero matrix.

Comment: Yes, I just caught that myself.